# Dynamic dependency between Inno Setup components

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I have three components. Two of them both depend on the third one. Is there a programmatic way to automatically check the box for the third component when either of the other two components are checked for installation?

This behavior is analogous to that of nested components, but these would be at the same level and I can't make use of that feature. Would be nice if Inno offered a way for inter-component dependencies, but until then...

**UPDATE**
Perhaps a fictitious example of what I envision would help:

```
[Components]
Name: "parent1"; Description: "app 1"
Name: "parent2"; Description: "app 2"; Depends: parent1
Name: "parent2\child"; Description: "feature"
Name: "parent3"; Description: "app 3"; Depends: parent1
Name: "parent3\child"; Description: "feature"
```

Comment: Does parent 1 need to be optional? and does the check state need to actually change? Inno can handle expressionw hen doing the install, e.g.: `Components: parent1 or parent2 or parent3` This will cause it to install that component. Maybe you could condition any UI/icons on just `parent1`.

Comment: @Deanna Yes, it does rather need to be individually selectable. To make things clear, the package is an SDK with various libraries. Some of them depend on the others. You can imagine the complexity this could generate.

Comment: @TLama I wish you had kept your answer as that's what helped me arrive at this approximate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck := @ComponentsClickCheck;
end;

procedure ComponentsClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListBox: TNewCheckListBox;
  parent1_top: Integer;
  parent2_top: Integer;
  parent3_top: Integer;
begin
  ListBox := TNewCheckListBox(Sender);
  parent1_top := 0;
  parent2_top := 1;
  parent3_top := 3;
  (* Check if parent2_top was selected. *)
  if (ListBox.State[parent2_top] = cbChecked) or
    (ListBox.State[parent2_top] = cbGrayed) then begin
    (* Check a dependent component. *)
    ListBox.CheckItem(parent1_top, coCheckWithChildren);
  end;
  (* Check if parent3_top was selected. *)
  if (ListBox.State[parent3_top] = cbChecked) or
    (ListBox.State[parent3_top] = cbGrayed) then begin
    (* Check a dependent component. *)
    ListBox.CheckItem(parent1_top, coCheckWithChildren);
  end;
end;
```

There is one side affect that the "dependency" becomes unchangeable until a "depending" component is deselected. Changing the Enabled state of the dependency for visual clarification would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a child component will by default automatically select its parent too (although you can disable that).  This sounds like exactly the behaviour you want though -- you're just thinking of it backwards.

Say that you have components A and B, which are independent.  You also have components C and D, each of which can be installed separately to each other but require component B to be installed.

```
[Components]
Name: "A"; Description: "app 1"
Name: "B"; Description: "app 2"
Name: "B\C"; Description: "feature C of app 2"
Name: "B\D"; Description: "feature D of app 2"
```

Given this arrangement, the user will be able to select A or B by themselves if they wish; they can also choose to add C or D (or not).  But selecting C or D will force B to be selected too.

(Note: this assumes that you have other entries conditional on all of these, in particular on B by itself.  If you're just testing the checkboxes by themselves and haven't added the `Components:` conditionals yet then you will have to add `Flags: checkablealone` to B in order to get the desired behaviour.)

For a closer approximation of your example above, try this:

```
[Components]
Name: "app1"; Description: "app 1"
Name: "app1\app2"; Description: "app 2"
Name: "app1\app2\child"; Description: "feature"
Name: "app1\app3"; Description: "app 3"
Name: "app1\app3\child"; Description: "feature"
```

App 1 can be installed by itself, and app 2 can be installed separately from app 3 -- but choosing either app 2 or app 3 will force app 1 to be included too.  (And yes, this will appear as a visible hierarchy -- but you probably should show that anyway so that the user knows why their choices are being forced in this way.)

Another possibility: if there's no reason for the user to need to install app1 by itself, then you can just remove it from the components entirely.  Simply change the conditions from `Components: app1` to `Components: app2 or app3`.  (Or if app2 and app3 are the only alternatives, and they both require app1, then remove the condition entirely.)

Comment: Yes, I've thought of doing it this way, but it doesn't scale well, it becomes convoluted. I gave a simple example to make a point, I'm trying to solve a larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentsClickCheck does not provide a reference to changed Item. But, we can track it by storing previous checked state of all items in an array. So, this way we can solve the *dependency becomes unchangeable until a depending component is deselected* issue.